# Issues writing currency symbols to file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write to a file:

```
private async writeToFile(data: any) {
    try {
        fs.writeFile(filePath as string, JSON.stringify(data), 'utf8', (error: any) => {
            if (error) {
                logger.error(`[JSON] Error while saving file : ${error}`);
            }
            logger.info('The file has been saved!');
        });
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(`[JSON] Error while saving file : ${error}`);
    }
}
```

where data has:

```
var data = [{label:'Egyptian Pound £', value: 'E£'}, {"label":"Albanian Lek-AL","value":"AL"}];
```

When I write to file, the characters are saved as `{label: Egyptian Pound E�, value: E�}`

**The data array is created from a multi line string returned from server:**

```
Egyptian Pound|E£   
Albanian Lek|AL
```

**Code to create the data array:**

```
const currencyArr = response
    .split('\n')
    .map(val => val.trim())
    .reduce((arr, currencyString) => {
        arr.push({
            label: currencyString.split('|')[0] + '-' + currencyString.split('|')[1],
            value: currencyString.split('|')[1]
        });
        return arr;
    }, []);
this.writeToFile(currencyArr);
```

I am not sure why this is happening. As per docs, node supports UTF-8 encoding by default

Comment: Can't reproduce, I tried your code and the file written contained exactly `[{"label":"Egyptian Pound £","value":"E£"}]`. Node 12.14.1

Comment: what is file type?

Comment: How do you view the file? What editor are you using? Does it correctly detect the encoding?

Comment: In my test, I wrote the data to "test.txt" and opened it with VS code, worked perfectly. Not sure what OP uses though

Comment: Are you sure the software you are using to read the file opens it with UTF-8 encoding ? Also fs.writeFile default encoding is alreadu UTF-8 : https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Comment: @ManjeetThakur File type I am saving is filename.json

Comment: @JeremyThille Which node version you are using?

Comment: @Seblor I am using notepad++ to open it. It opens up the file with UTF8 by default

Comment: @JoachimSauer I am using notepad++ to open it. It opens up the file with UTF8 by default

Comment: It seems your writing code is correct (as far as I know, I'm no node expert) and Notepad++ using UTF-8 is a good enough check that the output file is probably wrong. So the next place I'd start looking at is your input: is the code you show above **exactly** how `data` is initialized?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Updated the question and mentioned how data is initialized

Comment: @kittu I mentioned it, Node 12.14.1

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can find this kind of thing happen is if your JS file is the one not encoded in UTF8.

Make sure the JS file is saved in the UTF8 encoding, so the string in your script can be saved to the corresponding encoding.

Comment: I am using visual studio code for development. How do I check if file is in UTF-8?

Comment: @kittu look at the bottom right corner, the encoding should be specified, or use the palette command (ctrl + shift + P) and type "encoding"

Comment: Try creating a new file, double check if it is encoded in UTF8, then paste your code. There most likely is something wrong in your script, and I have seen people having to resort to recreating a file and make it work.

Comment: I mean recreating the source file.